# How convert xml to csv file using python (in row)?

Tags: python, xml, csv

I want to encode this xml document in cvs. I tried but it does not work I do not know what I'm doing wrong.I'm new on this.

There is the xml that i want to convert

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<Shot 
  Shotcode = "30AA" 
  ShotDate = "4/2/2000"> 

 <Images> 

  <Image 
   ImageNumber="103" 
   RawFileName="18_Shot_30AA.jpg" /> 
  <Image 
   ImageNumber="104"  
   RawFileName="17_Shot_30AA.jpg" /> 
  <Image 
   ImageNumber="105" 
   RawFileName="14_Shot_30AA" /> 
 </Images> 

 <Metrics> 
  <Metric 
   Name = "30AA" 
   TypeId = "163" 
   Value = "0" /> 

 <Metric 
  Name = "Area" 
  TypeId = "10" 
  Value = "63" /> 
 </Metrics> 

</Shot>
```

I code this in that form, in order to complete some example and is not the complete program but show what i'm doing.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

tree = ET.parse("30AA.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

30AA = open('30AA.csv', 'w+')
csvwriter = csv.writer(30AA)
head = []

count = 0   #loops
for member in root.findall('Shot'):
Shot = []
if count == 0:
    ShotCode = member.find('ShotCode').tag
    head.append(ShotCode)
    ShotDate = member.find('ShotDate').tag
    head.append(ShotDate)
    csvwriter.writerow(head)
    count = count + 1   
ShotCode = member.find('ShotCode').txt
Shot.append(ShotCode)
ShotDate = member.find('ShotDate').txt
Shot.append(ShotDate)   
30AA.close()
```

the result that i expect is

```
Shotcode    30AA    
ShotDate    4/2/2000    

Imagen  103 

Imagen  104 

Imagen  105 

Name TypeId Value
30AA  163   0
area  10    63
```

Comment: What you show as expected result is not a csv file. Why do you want to use the csv module to produce a non csv file? All csv files are text files, but not all text files are Comma Separated Values files...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I think I see whats going wrong, the major problem is mostly in reading the xml It just looks like its a csv thing.

The root of your xml is a Shot tag, so you can't use root.findall('Shot') to get all the  tags since root is already  and it doesn't have any Shot's inside it. 
So that why your not getting anything in your output.

Also when you want to get the attributes of a tag you use .attrib['name_of_attribute'] so for example instead of member.find('ShotCode').tag should be member.attrib['ShotCode']

That changes the rest of the script quite a bit but you then need to do something like this:

```
root = tree.getroot()

_30AA = open('30AA.csv', 'w+')
csvwriter = csv.writer(_30AA)
head = []

ShotCode = root.attrib['Shotcode']

csvwriter.writerow(['ShotCode', ShotCode])
head.append(ShotCode)
ShotDate = root.attrib['ShotDate']
csvwriter.writerow(['ShotDate', ShotDate])
# member is going to be the <Images> and <Metrics>
for member in root.getchildren():

    submembers = member.getchildren()
    # Write the names of the attributes as headings
    keys = submembers[0].attrib.keys()
    csvwriter.writerow(keys)
    for submember in submembers:

        row_data = [submember.attrib[k] for k in keys]
        csvwriter.writerow(row_data )

_30AA.close()
```

Will give you what you want